# Grouping and Counting data from part of id in laravel

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-10, laravel-controller

I have data like this :

TSAB001001
TSAB001002
TSAB001003
TSAB002001
TSAB002002
TSAB002003
TSIB001001
TSIB001002
TSIB001003
TSIB002001
TSIB002002
TSIB002003

I want to display it in blade :

- TSA

  - BOO1

    - TSAB001001
    - TSAB001002
    - TSAB001003
      Count: 3
  - B002

    - TSAB002001
    - TSAB002002
    - TSAB002003
      Count: 3
- TSI

  - BOO1

    - TSIB001001
    - TSIB001002
    - TSIB001003
      Count: 3
  - B002

    - TSIB002001
    - TSIB002002
    - TSIB002003
      Count: 3

Can you please help me how to imlementation this in laravel controller and view ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel's Collection `map` and `groupBy` methods. First, we need to process the data so that we have a clear data structure to work with:

```
$data = collect([
    'TSAB001001',
    'TSAB001002',
    'TSAB001003',
    'TSAB002001',
    'TSAB002002',
    'TSAB002003',
    'TSIB001001',
    'TSIB001002',
    'TSIB001003',
    'TSIB002001',
    'TSIB002002',
    'TSIB002003'
])
// Iterate every value above to prepare the base data we need to group
->map(fn ($item) => [
    'value' => $item,
    'prefix' => substr($item, 0, 3),
    'subprefix' => substr($item, 3, 4)
])
// Group for first level prefix
->groupBy('prefix')
// Iterate each group above then group by the subprefix
->map(function ($item) {
    return $item->groupBy('subprefix');
});
```

Then we can use some nested loop to output the data:

```
<ul>
  @foreach($data as $prefix => $subprefixes)
    <li>
      {{ $prefix }}
      <ul>
        @foreach($subprefixes as $subprefix => $items)
          <li>
            {{ $subprefix }}
            <ul>
              @foreach($items as $item)
                <li>
                  {{ $item['value'] }}
                  @if($loop->last)
                    Count: {{ count($items) }}
                  @endif
                </li>
              @endforeach
            </ul>
          </li>
        @endforeach
      </ul>
    </li>
  @endforeach
</ul>
```

We can use special `$loop` variable inside a blade loop to do some helpful things, like checking if it was the last item (`$loop->last`).

Learn more from the official docs:

- [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections)
- [Blade's loop variable](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#the-loop-variable)